# Unity Spawning child with client authority

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I'm currently learning how this whole networking thing works in unity. In my code I'm creating a spaceship made from multiple prefabs.

It all starts with a single `Hardpoint`. A `Hardpoint` can hold a single object, which will be instantiated later on in the loop.

In the `PlayerController` (the starting point) i have this code to spawn the first object, the cockpit:

```
[Command]
void CmdOnConnect() {
    string json = GameObject.Find("TestPlayer").GetComponent<ComponentObject>().ToJSON();
    CompressedComponent compressedComponent = JsonUtility.FromJson<CompressedComponent>(json);
    gameObject.GetComponent<Hardpoint>().Hold(GameObject.Find("Component Repository").GetComponent<ComponentRepository>().cockpit[compressedComponent.componentNumber]);
    gameObject.GetComponent<Hardpoint>().SpawnComponent();
    gameObject.GetComponent<Hardpoint>().RollThroughDecompression(compressedComponent);
    Camera.main.GetComponent<PlayerCamera>().player = gameObject;
}
```

Next up is the `SpawnComponent()` code, located in the `Hardpoint` script:

```
public void SpawnComponent() {
    Clear();
    CmdSpawn();
}
```

CmdSpawn, also located in `Hardpoint`:

```
[Command]
public void CmdSpawn()
{
    Debug.Log("[COMMAND] Spawning " + holds.name);
    heldInstance = Instantiate(holds, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
    heldInstance.transform.SetParent(transform);
    NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(heldInstance, transform.root.gameObject);
}
```

And finally `RollThroughDecompression`, which just calls the `Decompress()` function:

```
public void RollThroughDecompression(CompressedComponent c) {
    heldInstance.GetComponent<ComponentObject>().Decompress(c);
}
```

And just to leave no information out, `Decompress()`:

```
public void Decompress(CompressedComponent c) {
    componentType = (Type)Enum.Parse(typeof(Type), c.componentType);
    componentNumber = c.componentNumber;
    UpdateHardPoints();
    GameObject[] typeRepository = GetRepository(componentType);

    //update children 
    int point = 0;
    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        Hardpoint hardpoint = child.GetComponent<Hardpoint>();
        if (hardpoint != null) {
            if (c.hardpoints[point] != null) {
                //get the hardpoint's repository
                GameObject[] hardpointRepo = GetRepository((Type)Enum.Parse(typeof(Type), c.hardpoints[point].componentType));
                //set the hardpoint to hold this object
                hardpoint.Hold(hardpointRepo[c.hardpoints[point].componentNumber]);
                hardpoint.SpawnComponent();
                hardpoint.RollThroughDecompression(c.hardpoints[point]);
                point++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry the code's a little messy/confusing but I've been driven up the walls trying to figure out why newly spawned objects don't have `client authority` with the exception of the first object spawned (likely because it's called from the `PlayerController`). I've been stuck on this problem for days now. Newly spawned objects are being set as children of the local player object and are even spawned with `NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority` yet when testing:

`Trying to send command for object without authority.` when calling `CmdSpawn()`.

`NetworkManager`:
[image]

The result i'm getting:

[image]

As you can see, the cockpit (very first part) gets spawned as expected. but parts mounted on those `Hardpoints` don't. To clarify, the `EmptyHardpoint` is just that. A hardpoint with no children, just an empty game object with the `hardpoint` script and `playercontroller` attached to it. The cockpit prefab also includes the `img` and `hardpoints`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have forget to add your child Spawn in the Spawn list of [NetworkManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetManager.html).

[image]

Comment: Incorrect. That was my first guess as well, but the first component that should be spawned, does get spawned, others dont. i'll post a screenshot in a moment.

Comment: if you are spawning separately so assign separately

Comment: Sorry, looked at it wrong. Updated, but unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: I'm getting more warnings now though. all `hardpoints` have a networkidentity because of the script attached, it's a `networkbehavior` so i can't remove it. I'll shift some code around, see if i can get rid of the warning messages and get back to you on this. i think we're on to something here, thanks so far!